# How to see the react errors in the source component instead of in the bundle.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whe my react app fails I only can see the error referal to the bundle.js file not to the original component that generate it, so its impossible to me to know which is the  source line that generate this error:

[image: error refers to bundle.js generated file, but no to original CrearTurno.js file]

```html
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.10",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You either disabled source maps or ran the app in the production mode

Comment: I execute it with yarn start

Comment: That is not helpful. You can define whatever you want as `start` command with yarn. Show the contents of your `package.json`

Comment: I ahve just added the package.jason content in the original question.

Comment: I think that is any limitation of webpack that is used by default by create-react-app

Comment: It seems like that